# how to make a chat but in python

Tags: python, bots, steam

hello i am newbe on programming and i want some help with the thing i am trying to do

**1** how can i connect my bot with the steam servers

**2** lest say someone sends me a message on steam and i am away but i left steam open and the bot is running. and someone sends me a message how can i make the bot say something like this **"right now (name) is away but you can leave your message on this chat box"**

**3** and if you can tell me how to do this in python i know how to create basic commands that is all thank you

Answer (score 0):

take look this link!
[github.chatbot](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=chat%20bot&type=Repositories)